# Advanced jQuery selector that needs a jQuery ninja to answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am looking for a jQuery guru to help me out on this. I have limited access to the code because it is a WordPress theme. My script has to go in the indicated area and if this can't be done with just jQuery, I would love suggestions that use JavaScript as well. Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

I need to grab the "href" link that is on EACH button of class 'gdlr-button' and wrap the href around the image that is inside EACH div.personnel-author-image

```
<div class="personnel-item">
    <div class="personnel-author-image gdlr-skin-border">
        <img src="/my/image-location.jpg" alt="" width="720" height="480">
    </div>
    <div class="personnel-info">
        <div class="personnel-author gdlr-skin-title">My Name</div>
        <div class="personnel-position gdlr-skin-info">My Position</div>
    </div>
    <div class="personnel-content gdlr-skin-content">
        <p>
            <a class="gdlr-button small" id="link-joni" href="/my/unique/link-destination">Learn More</a>
            <script>
            // MY SCRIPT GOES HERE
                .......
            </script>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
... And Repeat
<div class="personnel-item">
  <div class="personnel-author-image gdlr-skin-border">
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? I mean, I'm sure a lot of ppl would love to help you. But not do the work for you…

Comment: Your script shouldn't go there at all, it should be included with wp_enqeue_script, not just included as part of the content with a script tag in every item.

Comment: And here's the script -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qs8Lps00/**

Comment: I'm not trying to get anyone to do all the work. I have been racking my brain on this all morning. I've tried all kinds of things from using combinations of the wrap(), find(), closest(), parentsuntil() functions. I was hoping someone could see something I didn't. Nothing is working fully. I got the wrap to work, but it only would wrap the first element or it would wrap all the elements with the same link.

Comment: @adeneo, you are a NINJA!!!!!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @adeneo for this script. He truly is a Ninja!

jsfiddle.net/qs8Lps00

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.gdlr-button').each(function() {
        var img = $(this).closest('.personnel-content').siblings('.personnel-author-image').find('img');
        img.wrap('<a href="'+this.href+'"></a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can get `img` with one less method call.  `$(this).closest('.personnel-item').find('.personnel-author-image img');`

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(function() {
        $('.personnel-author-image > img').wrap(function() {
            return $('<a/>',{href:$(this).closest('.personnel-item').find('.gdlr-button').attr('href')});
        });        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="personnel-item">
  <div class="personnel-author-image gdlr-skin-border">
    <img src="/my/image-location.jpg" alt="" width="720" height="480">
  </div>
  <div class="personnel-info">
    <div class="personnel-author gdlr-skin-title">My Name</div>
    <div class="personnel-position gdlr-skin-info">My Position</div>
  </div>
  <div class="personnel-content gdlr-skin-content">
    <p>
      <a class="gdlr-button small" id="link-joni" href="/my/unique/link-destination">Learn More</a>
      <script>
        // MY SCRIPT GOES HERE
        .......
      </script>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Include the script in `wp_enqeue_script` as suggested by @adeneo:

```
    $('.personnel-author-image > img').wrap(function() {
        return $('<a/>',{href:$(this).closest('.personnel-item').find('.gdlr-button').attr('href')});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will go through each .personnel-item and grab the href and wrap the img tag in an a tag

```
$(".personnel-item").each(function(){
    var href = $(this).find(".gdlr-button").attr("href");
    $(this).find(".personnel-author-image img").wrap( "<a href='"+href+"'></a>" );
});
```

Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L26b4hdd/)

Answer (score 0):

Here a short snippet to do what you suggest:

```js
$('.personnel-item').each(function(){
 var href =$(this).find('.gdlr-button').prop('href');
 var img = $(this).find('.personnel-author-image').html();
 $(this).find('.personnel-author-image').html('<a href="'+href+'">'+ img +'</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="personnel-item">
  [...]
<div class="personnel-author-image gdlr-skin-border">
        <img src="http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834" alt="" width="25" height="">
    </div>
 <div class="personnel-content gdlr-skin-content">
        <p>
            <a class="gdlr-button small" id="link-joni" href="/my/unique/link-destination">Learn More</a>
        </p>
    </div>
  [...]
    </div>
    <div class="personnel-item">
      [...]
    <div class="personnel-author-image gdlr-skin-border">
        <img src="http://nicolewarner.com/images/stories/Blog_Pictures/Perspective_August_2014/number-2-hi.png" alt="" width="25" height="">
    </div>
 <div class="personnel-content gdlr-skin-content">
        <p>
            <a class="gdlr-button small" id="link-joni" href="/my/other/link-destination">Learn More</a>
        </p>
    </div>
      [...]
    </div>
```

Greetings from Vienna